# Query Regarding PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, filtering, dax

I am new to Power BI and stuck at a problem:

Below is an example sample data. I need to find out the count of users who 'only' performed event 'B'
So, as per the example given, the output should be one user, because user 3 performed only event 'B'.
Any idea how can I write DAX query for this problem?

```
User    Event
1       A
2       A
1       B
1       C
3       B
2       B
1       D
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is to use set functions:

- calculate list of users who performed "B" events
- calculate list of users who performed non-"B" events
- use EXCEPT function to find users in the first list who are not in the second list  (that is, users who had event B but did not have non-B events)

DAX measure:

```
B Only User Count =
VAR B_Users = CALCULATETABLE ( DISTINCT ( Data[User] ), Data[Event] = "B" )

VAR Non_B_Users = CALCULATETABLE ( DISTINCT ( Data[User] ), Data[Event] <> "B" )

VAR B_Only_Users = EXCEPT ( B_Users, Non_B_Users )

RETURN COUNTROWS ( B_Only_Users )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3679147/rado
Dear @RADO This worked out pretty smooth! Thanks for answering my question. I have a two follow-up questions, 1. What if I have the user column in different table and not in 'Data' table I tried, VAR B_Users = CALCULATETABLE ( DISTINCT ( DifferentTable[User] ), Data[Event] = "B" ) But this is giving me blank output. 2. To extend my original question, what if I want to calculate list of users who performed only event B or C or more than two events? Do I have to manually write the above DAX for each event and then count distinct user id

Comment: @KunalKochar - I recommend to post a new question with these additional requirements. Show your data model diagram, and provide an example of the desired results. Send me a link to the new question, I'll look at it.